# Why did FMA 2003 Wrath (King Bradley) keep his skull?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-2003

In FMA 2003, homunculi are paralysed if they come into close proximity of a part of their original bodies. Wrath (Fuhrer King Bradley in 2003) was defeated by Mustang after his son brought him his skull, which he usually kept locked in a safe.

Why did he keep his skull? Why did he not simply destroy it or dispose of it in a place that he could not be traced to?

Comment: It could have been a way to make sure he always knew and (theoretically) could control where it was.

Comment: @kuwaly Then why not destroy it instead?

Comment: We don't know. It can't be answered, since not enought information is given. Maybe he wanted to keep it near. Maybe he couldn't destroy it. Maybe it was just a plot device to defeat him.